# Email service address missing in Email to Case

Tags: email2case

Hi i have setup an email to case. When i created routing address for that it is not generating email service address. Field is showing empty. Below is the screenshot for the same. Help me
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Please check the checkbox Enable On-Demand Service in Email-to-Case Settings to fix your issue.
Thanks!